# What's the best way of sending data only when client is ready?

Tags: java, unity-game-engine, tcp

I'm writing a multi-client java server for a game made in unity. The server has many Threads as Clients connected. The problem is that I need to receive some data from the client, process it in the server and send back some other data that the client can use only in an other scene (the client changes scene soon after sending data), but the client can use the response only in the 2nd scene. How can I send data to the Client only when the scene is loaded?

I temporarily used Sleep like so to wait the scene to be loaded before sending data

```
void foo(String data, Player player){
    //processing data
    Thread.sleep(500);
    player.send(response);
}
```

but ofcourse this solution is really bad

My idea was creating a queue HashMap containing the player and the data so I can send some signal from the client and reply from the server with the queued data something like

```
HashMap<Player,String> queue = new HashMap<>();

void foo(String data,Player player){
    //processing data
    queue.put(player,response);
}

void clientIsReady(Player player){
   if(queue.containsKey(player))
        player.send(queue.get(player));
}
```

is this approach any good or is there a better way to solve this problem?
Should I send data before passing to the 2nd scene maybe? (I don't really like this solution)

Thanks to anyone that helps me

Comment: You could buffer server responses on the client, and process them in the next scene.

Comment: Yeah thank you for your solution, as I said I don't really like this solution, but It's probably the easiest to implement

Comment: I'm not sure when your "sending the data" in Scene 1 is supposed to occur but if it is at the end of the scene (before transition to Scene 2) why not just make it part of Scene 2 loading.  i.e. put it behind a black screen with a spinner.

Comment: Well the loading of the second scene is very quick and even doing in that way the problem persists